# Binary Multiplier

Tags: binary, minecraft

Could someone provide me with the basic logic behind binary multipliers. I'm currently working on a 4-bit multiplier in the game Minecraft and have a design for a 2-bit multiplier, but can't find one for a 4-bit and can't figure it out.. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Wouldn't a 256-byte lookup table do the trick?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're talking about, but I don't think that would work in Minecraft...

Answer (score 1):

The elementary multiplication algorithm is exactly the same as with decimal numbers. The binary "bitwise multiplication" is just a logical AND of the bits. I assume you are familiar with the logic of adder, as you have implemented a two-bit multiplier.

What you need to do:

```
 1) Generate partial products of the 4-bit words

     1010   (10 in decimal)
   x 0101   (5 in decimal)
---------
     1010
    0000
   1010
  0000

 2) Sum up the partial products
     00001010
   + 00000000
    ----------
     00001010
   + 00101000
    ----------
     00110010
   + 00000000
   ----------
     00110010   (50 in decimal)
```

For advanced multipliers, you may look for "Booth multiplier"and "Dadda multiplier". In case you are not familiar with concept of digital adder, please look information for "Ripple carry adder".